# What does the @ operator do in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I was learning python the from Learn Python the hard way and upon [ex37](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex37.html) they expect us to conduct a search. I do not know what the @ operator does. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: it means decorator. Like I thought, it's a dupe!

Comment: [Decorators I: Introduction to Python Decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808)

Comment: You will find this useful: http://symbolhound.com/

Comment: This question has some really in depth answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: This is the best place to learn about decorators, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: @jamylak AFAIK google strips most non alphanumeric characters from searches, hence a google search doesn't not yield the desired results.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes but if the OP had searched his exact question in Google he would have found it. Stackoverflow would have also suggested it to OP but OP still posted it for some reason

Comment: @jamylak I agree that the OP should have searched more before asking, but anyway searching `What does the @ operator do in python?` on google and StackOverflow does *not* yield a related result in the *first* page(at least for me).